# How many steps to get zero

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Can someone solve this in Javascript?

Given a non-negative integer num, return the number of steps to reduce it to zero. If the current number is even, you have to divide it by 2, otherwise, you have to subtract 1 from it.

Example 1:

Input: num = 14
Output: 6
Explanation:
Step 1) 14 is even; divide by 2 and obtain 7.
Step 2) 7 is odd; subtract 1 and obtain 6.
Step 3) 6 is even; divide by 2 and obtain 3.
Step 4) 3 is odd; subtract 1 and obtain 2.
Step 5) 2 is even; divide by 2 and obtain 1.
Step 6) 1 is odd; subtract 1 and obtain 0.
Example 2:

Input: num = 8
Output: 4
Explanation:
Step 1) 8 is even; divide by 2 and obtain 4.
Step 2) 4 is even; divide by 2 and obtain 2.
Step 3) 2 is even; divide by 2 and obtain 1.
Step 4) 1 is odd; subtract 1 and obtain 0.
Example 3:

Input: num = 123
Output: 12

Also is this an example of a recursion question?

```
var numberOfSteps  = function(num) {
    
};


///What I have tried

var numberOfSteps  = function(num) {
    if(Math.sign(num) === -1){
      console.log('Number has to be positive')
    }
    else if(num % 2 === 0){
      num = num/2 
      if(num % 2 !== 0){
        num = num - 1
        if(num !== 0){
           num = num / 2 
           if(num % 2 !== 0){
              num = num - 1
             if(num % 2 === 0)
           }
        }
      }
    }
};

console.log(numberOfSteps(14))
```

Comment: Is there anything you tried?

Comment: When [asking about homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) please provide some examples of what you tried, and ask for help debugging specific parts of your code. Simply pasting a homework question shows no effort and your end and will likely not lead to any answers.

Comment: Yes I tried. But i had a lot of conditionals. I can share that code if you want to see it.

Comment: Sharing your attempt(s) is the correct approach.  We need to see what difficulty you are having so we can point out places where you are going wrong, to nudge you in the correct direction.  You will learn more this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply simulate the process by continuously halving and decrementing the number (as appropriate) until it reaches `0` while counting the number of iterations.

```js
var numberOfSteps  = function(num) {
    let steps = 0;
    while(num > 0){
        if(num % 2 === 0) num /= 2;
        else --num;
        ++steps;
    }
    return steps;
};
console.log(numberOfSteps(123));
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions  Under "Answering and moderating homework questions", complete solutions should not be provided to homework questions.

Comment: Alternatively, you can just look at the number of ones in the binary representation of `num`. I think that would typically lead to a better runtime.

Comment: @EkeshKumar There are 6 ones in the binary representation of 123.

Comment: @hev1 Oops, I was originally wrong: The answer isn't just the number of ones in the binary representation, but it's close. `return num ? __builtin_popcount(num) + 31 - __builtin_clz(num) : 0;` will give the minimum steps to reduce to `0` (from https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-steps-to-reduce-a-number-to-zero/). Then I think you can make small adjustments to reduce to one. `__builtin_popcount(num)` returns the number of ones in `num`, and `__builtin_clz(num)` counts the number of zeros in `num`.